# RapidSVN added question marks to all of my files

Tags: svn, rapidsvn

I was using RapidSVN for the first time and played around with the features. I wanted to download a file to my home folder and now all of my file icons have a question mark on them. How can I remove it?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the icon to show that the file is not in your repository. To remove them you'll need to delete the working copy, delete the .svn directory from your home directory (assuming you don't already have a legitimate use for that) and then delete the bookmark from within RapidSVN.

Generally you would check out files from a repository into a new directory, not one that contains other files already. There is a getting started guide at http://www.rapidsvn.org/index.php/Getting_to_know_RapidSVN

Edit: If you want to keep the working copy you could also choose to not show files from the repository. From the Edit menu, uncheck the "Show unversioned files".

Comment: I tried everything, but I'm unable to remove the question mark. I went as far as uninstalling RapidSVN using Revo Uninstaller Pro, and deep cleaning (registry and junk files) using Advanced SystemCare. But the icon is still there. Help!